# How can I accomplish gradient effects in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, gradient

I'd like the gradient to have more depth like the red  graphic has

[image]

[image]

Comment: Inverst and apply gradient map?

Comment: @joojaa or just use an inverted gradient

Comment: @Wolff yes off course.

Comment: Hi eve and welcome to GDSE. It would be really helpful if you could somehow edit the title and maybe add some text *describing* the effect. I'm sure this question has been asked before, but probably with the same "how to make this:" title. That makes it impossible to search for and that's probably why you weren't able to find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this effect with a *Gradient Map* adjustment layer.

[image]

Start with playing with the *presets* and then customize the *gradient stops* to achieve the effect you want. Notice how the gradient can easily be inverted by clicking *Reverse* in the *Properties* panel.